# http not redirecting to https using Url Rewrite for whole URL in IIS 10 (URL containing parameters)

Tags: c#, http, redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I have tried below configuration added from IIS console, but this works only for main domain
For example
works for- http://example.com redirects to https://example.com
but not working in following case
http://example.com/abc/some?Parameter 
not redirecting to 
https://example.com/abc/some?Parameter

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                       <add input="{HTTP}" pattern="^OFF$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

According  to your url rewrite rules, I found you add both http and https condition.  That means no matter you use http or https, it will always not redirect to https.

The right url rewrite rule is as below:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to http" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*" negate="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very very important step that should take care, before setup a redirect configure.

in web Sites project --> Actions(in the right) --> Bindings , the content will like below:
[Binding Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bw6u.png)

You take carefully the yellow color part, the yellow part is your original web IP address. This original IP address must exist in "Site Bindings", **without the yellow part the URL redirect will not working anymore**.

The following config is my current IIS URL redirect setting:

```
    <rewrite>
        <globalRules>
            <rule name="Http redirect to Https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost:8080" />   <-- the Red one should match above Site Bindings original IP address
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://Your-Host-Name/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
            </rule>
        </globalRules>
    </rewrite>
```